# Is there a way to distort an image to look like a wave effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

I have a cup of coffee with 'wave' steam going up and I wonder if there is a (preferred) CSS way to distortion so it would look like a wave with some blur, something like  a [Fata Morgana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fata_Morgana_%28mirage%29) effect.

I uploaded a copy of my cup. And [here](https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/0/AACc1_Z8Qg0Cxx9mEQ8zUb_BJhhgB6g9EDyrWg5yJMTYVg/10/112059847/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/steam.png/MU0JPl9NVbiL_3gXY7dc3XHItdM-NVi3HWa59tsVZUU?size=1280x960&size_mode=2) is my steam.

[image: Here]

Comment: I think this is a valid question?

Comment: Your steam is an 403 error.

Comment: Why vote to close? It would be pretty awesome to leverage a CSS effect to make the coffee steam actually shimmer.

Comment: Thx for the support. It's quite an interesting effect and as much as i looked i haven't find anything familiar yet.

Comment: Using CSS to do this would be cool, but I don't entirely see the purpose in that. Why not just apply it directly to the image in photoshop?

Comment: @user1803405 so that it can be made to move on the page in response to user interaction? Why do people make their webpages "snow" in the winter?

Comment: @user1803405 - he is after a dynamic effect with the steam moving. Photoshop of course can't do that, but CSS3 animations can.

Comment: This would probably be best as an animated GIF, where you'll have more flexibility for creating your shimmer.

Comment: Try canvas animations. Also it can be done with SVG.

Comment: @mrtsherma He can do that with a gif, using photoshop.

Answer (score 7):

Real life steam doesn't really work that way.  There's a lot of flowing and randomness that  would be impossible (at least for me) to get out of a static image.

Nevertheless, I think an approximate effect can be achieved with some skewing and fading.  You can use CSS animations to do this:

```
@keyframes steam {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: skewX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;        
    }
    25% { transform: skewX(10deg); opacity: .8; }
    75% { transform: skewX(-10deg); opacity: .8; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/wxfg5/1/

This animates the skewing and opacity back and forth, so it's not so random.  You can of course add more frames to the animation to give it a seemingly random look or make the pattern harder to follow.

Real steam moves more randomly.  You can't do randomness like that with CSS alone (that I know of), so you have to go full JS:

```
var frameTime = 200;

var transition = 'all ' + (frameTime / 1000) + 's linear';
img.style.WebkitTransition = transition;
img.style.transition = transition;

setInterval(function () {
    var skew = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1);
    skew = 'skewX(' + skew + 'deg)';
    img.style.transform = skew;
    img.style.WebkitTransform = skew;
}, frameTime);
```

Adding opacity changes or other skewing such as `skewY` (which may be effective) should be fairly trivial with the above framework.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/wxfg5/2/

Comment: great work man!